# Save file in NetBeans project with ISO-8859-1 encoding with some characters in UTF-8

Tags: netbeans, character-encoding

In Netbeans environment I was checkout the project that with `ISO-8859-1 character encoding`, but looks like in some HTML (TPL) file some characters is in `ISO-8859-1` and, also, in `UTF-8`.

Also in head of file I have set:

> 

And when I try to change something (even type simple space) in this file and try to Save then Netbeans doesn't allow me to save with message:

> The encodings iso-8859-1 specified in meta tag of the document
>   <> is invalid or the document contains characters which
>   cannot be saved using this encoding. Do you want to save the file
>   using UTF-8 encoding? YES / NO

If I use "YES" the file will be in `UTF-8`, that is not suitable for project encoding `ISO-8859-1` and without support appropriate characters.

If I use "NO" it does not save this file at all.

How I can save this file in `ISO-8859-1` and use it for all project?

Answer (score 0):

I simple convert file without NetBeans IDE.

1) cat (filename) | iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 | iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 > (new_filename)

2) I open (new_filename) in gedit (Linux editor) and save it in ISO-8859-1 in the Netbeans project directory and then I simple reopen it in Netbeans and now it's possible to save without warnings.

General encoding steps:

1) Project properties in the Netbeans should be set "ISO-8859-1".

2) Set header of XML/HTML files for right encoding (ISO-8859-1).
I.e. for HTML files:

```
<meta charset='iso-8859-1'>
```

3) Encode all files in project to "ISO-8859-1".

4) Check for default character encoding in Netbeans configuration.